# securty issue XOR

Tags: c#, encryption

is this password check algorithm safe to use in low security environment like local network

```
 static string keys = "qwertyuiopüõasdfghjklöäzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPÜÄÖLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM";
    static Int64 key = 0;
    public static bool check(string input)
    {
        string tmp = "";
        string encAnswer = "ỬốỒởỐỚ";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            tmp += keys.IndexOf(input[i]).ToString();
        }
        key = Int64.Parse(tmp);
        string res = "";
        char c;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            c = input[i];
            c = (char)(c ^ key);
            res += c;
        }
        if (res == encAnswer)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stick with hash algorithms, even in low security environments. Take a look on [SHA256 Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256.aspx)

Note you will not be able to recover original password by using hash algorithms.

**EDIT:** As OP noted, just using a hash algorithm isn't enough. You must to add a salt to make it harder to break. Some examples can be found here: [How To: Hash Data with Salt (C#/VB.NET)](http://www.obviex.com/samples/hash.aspx)

Comment: I agree on the hash approach but I'd avoid MD5 even for low security environments as it's now pretty easy to create hash collisions. I'd use SHA-256 instead

Answer (score 3):

**Obfuscation is not security.**

The XOR mechanism you describe is a recipe for future pain and embarrassment. You should probably avoid it and use the built-in features of the .NET and Windows platforms to implement security.

The problem with approaches to security like the one you describe is that most attacks on systems happen from within an organization. The fact that you feel your application needs a password mechanism at all implies that security is a relevant consideration. If security is indeed relevent, why opt for the *illusion of security* - spend a little more effort and get the real thing.

**Here are some reasons to go the full nine yards:**

1. Techniques to break XOR "encryption" schemes like the one you describe abound on the internet, and it requires very little knowledge and access to break such a scheme.
2. If successful, your application may grow to have more users than you might first imagine - don't trust that all of these users will be friendly and play by the rules.
3. Once in production, changes to an existing system are hard to justify and harder to make than before the code is released. It's also easier to *add missing functionality* than to change existing functionality.
4. Trust is hard (or impossible) t regain. The price of a security breach is often disproportional to the price of implementing security. Once trust is lost in a system's security or ability to protect user identity/information, it doesn't matter how good the application features are, people will lose confidence in the system as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

It's roughly comparable to a strip of adhesive tape used as a "lock" on an apartment door. If you have "low security" requirements, why don't you skip the password check completely?

Comment: so my sister can't access my personal web server.

Comment: Rubens: He simply asked if the algorithm he had implemented was safe and no, it is not. If he wanted a better solution, he could learn to ask for a better solution.

Comment: @Woland
What if she drops your computer ?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that there are quite extensive databases with hash codes so this renders Rubens Farias solution useless for me

http://askcheck.com/hash?hash=WOLAND

Even turning out lights maybe security improvident for home. especially when burglar has already broken in.

Comment: Rubens forgot to say that a password needs a SALT adding to it. This is a cryptographically random number which makes it much harder to do dictionary attacks ( as in the link you sent )